# Camera is not Detecting the face and showing details

Tags: python

I am getting a type error in my Python Code

Code:

```
my_cursor.execute("select Gender from student where Id=" + str(id))
          g = my_cursor.fetchone()
          g = "+".join(g)
```

error:

> `n="+".join(n)`

> TypeError: can only join an iterable

Comment: how is the title of your question related to the actual question? There's absolutely nothing about camera and face detection.

Comment: I am sorry i was not getting what was the error and how to write the description of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `my_cursor` as an iterable result

```
my_cursor.execute("select Gender from student where Id=" + str(id))
result = "+".join(my_cursor)
```

You can see more in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html)

Comment: Thank you although title mismatched the question i asked.